# Comma separate an array in React-Table?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react table with an accessor that is an array. I want to comma separate the values in my table since the output is very ugly right now. All the values looks like they are just a long string. How can I do this? It is the accessor called "ClientCodeRegional" I want to separate.

```
 return ([

            {
                Header: "Existing Users",
                headerStyle: { background: '#dedede' },
                columns: [
                      {
                        Header: "",
                        maxWidth: 30,
                        Filter: ({ filter, onChange }) =>
                            <NPHelpButton content={helpNode} title="Help" />,
                            Cell: (row) =>
                            {
                              return <span>
                              <select  className='tst myopt handy' onChange={evt => { this.handleSelectChange(evt, evt.target.value, row, this);}}>
                                <option value="">...</option>
                                <option value="CreateNew">Create new</option>
                                <option value="Edit">Modify this user</option>  
                              </select>
                            </span>
                            } 

                    },
                    {
                      Header: "Username / Email",
                      accessor: "Email",
                  },
                  {
                    Header: "Client Code Regional",
                    accessor: "ClientCodeRegional",
                },
                {
                  Header: "Role",
                  accessor: "Settings.Role",
              },
                  {
                    Header: "Open / Locked",
                    accessor: "Settings.IsLocked",
                }
                ]
            },

        ]);
```

This is the outcome from my code right now. The number is actually two numbers.

```
<div class="rt-td" style="flex: 100 0 auto; width: 100px;">5065735527</div>
```

Comment: What library are you using? Is this plain JSX?